# How to create admin user with only read customer permissions in Magento-2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, customer, user-roles

I have created one admin role with Customers/All Customers.

This user have permissions for access customers,modify customer details, delete customer.

But I want to restrict this user to delete customer, modify customer in Magento-2.1

How can do that?

Comment: help me anyone?